# How do I take my HTML template and add my PHP log in script to it?

Tags: facebook

I downloaded a free web template html. I created a data base using MySql and PHP. I now would like to take the PHP log in script I created and put it on to my HTML web page. I want users to have to sign up and log in to the site before accessing it.

I can access my log in screen going to my web site but its just a user name and password box and just looks like garbage I would like it to look like the rest of my website but with the log in boxs when you first arrive to the site. thanks!

Comment: so to do this do I just take the HTML coding to my existing site copy it, and paste it in to the .css file? thanks. Sorry I'm very new to this.

took me awhile to get the database and log in page sycned + email verification. I've got every thing working just need it too look like the rest of the site.

I do understand the style.css as that how most of my site is now, I just dont know how to go about taking the existing template and tranfering it in to the .css

Answer (score 0):

You can make CSS style-sheet so that your log-in page looks like the template and attach it to your log-in page like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
```